# how do I bind country from the given response to mat-select angular 10

Tags: angular

[image]

I am a beginner and new to angular, i dont even know to post code here, can anyone guide me how to manipulate the response data and fill the dropdown.

Comment: You can read about adding and formatting code here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Country" name="food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of country">
        {{item.country}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

ts

```
export class ClassExample {
  country = [
    { country: "A" },
    { country: "B" },
    { country: "C" },
    { country: "D" },
    { country: "E" }
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you want to show **`Country`** in the dropdown then you can iterate over you data set and bind value of **`<mat-option>`** to Country name, like shown below.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let info of data" [value]="info.Country">{{info.Country}}</mat-option>
```

For working example of your data refer this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-ico6z4?file=src/app/app.component.html)